# python: "mutable vectors are unhashable" error

Tags: python, sage

I am using the maths package SAGE, which is written in Python.

I am trying to manipulate some sets of vectors and I keep on getting the above error message. I have absolutely no idea what it is telling me, although I do understand what mutable means Can someone please explain in fairly simple conceptual terms what it is telling me is wrong?

Comment: Show us the entire exception stack trace and the code that causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Python cannot use the content of 'vectors' to build a set, because the 'vector object' is just a 'pointer' to its content: the content is not 'fixed' and you can change it re-using the same vector vatiable (Python would have to rebuild the set to keep it working).

So, you can use 'set' only of immutable objects (like tuples, strings, numbers).

E.g.

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [3, 4, 5]
>>> set([l1, l2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This is because you can change l1 and l2 (e.g. with .append).

```
>>> t1 = (1, 2, 3)
>>> t2 = (3, 4, 5)
>>> set([t1, t2])
set([(3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3)])
```

In this case you cannot change the content of t1 and t2.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are finding something like

```
sage: V = vector([1,2,3])
sage: W = vector([3,4,5])
sage: set([V,W])
<snip>
TypeError: mutable vectors are unhashable
sage:
```

You can fix this default setting in the following manner.

```
sage: V.set_immutable(); W.set_immutable()
sage: set([V,W])
set([(3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3)])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can only put hashable objects in [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)s:

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct [hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) objects.

For Python, it means that the object must implement a `__hash__` method, as well as `__eq__` or `__cmp__`.

Mutable objects do not implement such a method and can't be stored in a `set`. You can store an immutable sequence is a `set`, such as a `tuple` or `frozenset`.

Another quote from the docs:

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` or `__cmp__()` method). Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are. Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they all compare unequal, and their hash value is their `id()`.

Comment: thanks but that's still too technical for me ... the answers below kind-of solve it though.